# How do I use firebase ml kit with xamarin.forms?

Tags: visual-studio, firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-mlkit

I am trying to make an app in Xamarin.forms that needs to be able to detect text from images, and I decided to use Firebase ML Kit. How do I use ML Kit with Xamarin.forms, not just Xamarin android? If I can't, is there an alternative I can use with Xamarin iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see any Firebase MLKit package for Xamarin.Forms. There are only packages for Xamarin.Firebase.ML.Vision->Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.MLKit->Xamarin.IOS.

I think you should use alternatives like Microsoft Cognitive Service-> Computer Vision or Tesseract package. I had a change to implement both and Azure service's recognition is much better than Terresact. On the other hand Tesseract has an advantage, it can work offline and faster.

There are 2 ways to implement Microsoft Cognitive Service. First one is using their packages and other one is using  rest service. Similar result. Tesseract is offline, so you should use its package.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm actually adding a feature to an already existing app that uses ML Kit, so I can just use the Xamarin.Firebase.ML.Vision->Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.MLKit->Xamarin.IOS packages, right? Would I just have to write two different pieces of code(one for android, one for ios)?  If not, I will take a look at Microsoft Cognitive Service.